# Keep position in List when remove and add again items into a List

Tags: list, dart

For example, I have `4 items` displayed on the list, let's say `(A, B, C, D)` => with position `(0,1,2,3)`

Then I deleted `3 items` by querying `choices.removeWhere ((item) => item.title == data.type);` it's for `(A, B, C)` and then in the list means only showing `1 item` namely `A`.

Then I add the items back with the query `choices.add (Choice (title:" A "));` up to `C`.

Now the results in the list when adding are `(D, A, B, C)`.

Question: Do you think we can keep the position even if we do the `add` and `remove` commands so that the urinary remains still `(A, B, C, D)`?

This is my model and list:

```
class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.index});
  final String title;
  final int index;
}

List<Choice> choices = <Choice>[
  Choice(
    title: A,
    index: 0,
  ),
  Choice(
    title: B,
    index: 1,
  ),
  Choice(
    title: C,
    index: 2,
  ),
  Choice(
    title: D,
    index: 3,
  ),
];
```

Comment: Do you mean using the order from the letters, alphabetically? or some other field?

Comment: Based on the original position, the original position is `ABCD`, so when I remove then add again, the position still `ABCD`. Because in my case if I deleted 3 items (ABC), then I add in orders `CAB`. So in the list showing `DCAB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can remove some items from the list and then again re-add your items.

Use your `index` field to sort again your list.

Try this code, the important part is the **sorting**:

```
  List<Choice> choices = <Choice>[
    Choice(title: "Cat", index: 0),
    Choice(title: "Dog", index: 1),
    Choice(title: "Bird", index: 2),
  ];

  // removing 
  choices.removeWhere ((item) => item.title == "Cat");
  choices.removeWhere ((item) => item.title == "Dog");

  // adding
  choices.add (Choice (title:"Cat", index: 0));
  choices.add (Choice (title:"Dog", index: 1));

  // sorting by the "index"
  choices.sort((a, b) => a.index.compareTo(b.index));

  // print the list
  choices.forEach((n) => print(n.title));
```

Comment: Based on the original position, the original position is `ABCD`, so when I remove then add again, the position still `ABCD`. Because in my case if I deleted 3 items (ABC), then I add in orders `CAB`. So in the list showing `DCAB`

Comment: You need to have other field, like "position" and use it in the sort. See my updated answer.

Comment: And also can you edit your code like my code in the question?

Comment: I change the answer to include the index field and the sort based on that index